# Should I have a single POJO class representing all possible columns returned from a Room Table?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, pojo, android-room

This is currently my data class in Kotlin representing a File. Room is able to return columns by constructing POJO's that you specify in the return type as long as the column info matches. Depending on the use case, such as showing the model as a view or storing it, I require different columns. Should I create POJOs for each of those cases or use the one below since I can have null fields?

**My concern is primarily memory, since null values still create pointers that occupy space.** Maintaining different POJO's and updating them is a hassle - requires converters and factories. But the following model could also get bigger.

```
data class Photo(
val id: Long,
val name: String?,
val isFavourite: Boolean?,
val isPrivate: Boolean?,
val fileType: String?,
val dateTaken: Long?,
val height: Int?,
val width: Int?,
val location: String?)
```

Comment: Well, I personally would almost never start with focus on memory footage, but try to get a good coding model. If that requires small, focussed classes, I will create them. If smal classes will more confuse readers than help, I will use less classes. By trying to optimize memory with minimizing the amount of null pointers, you will almost always optimize an irrelevant part of your application. This said, I cannot answer your question directly.

Comment: Another thing that comes to my mind: What kind of file does your generically named data class represent? With attributes like "dateTaken", "height" and "width" this looks like an image file, but not a generic file. Is this also due to memory optimization, or might there be some flaws within the whole data model?

Comment: Kotlin's null safety would be useful so creating such objects would have no burden. Yes, it's an Image File. I renamed at the time of posting this. Sorry about that. The actual model is "Photo" in my project.

Answer (score 1):

When you're developing a model you should follow [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles. According to that you should build your model based on the answers to:

- Do all photos have filetype, id, height, and width: probably yes - this means this field should belong to photo.
- Do all photo have dateTaken, location, isPrivate etc - If no you could use association = Create POJO like PhotoInfo. From this perspective of view, you could create POJOs that are grouped by pairs etc.

As others noted in the commentaries you shouldn't worry about the space unless it's a bottleneck in your app. And by that I mean if you have a lot of objects and you're short on space. Or you could face this issue in the future. Which in most cases the answer is no.

Comment: Yes. I've been following various architectural patterns and although they are robust, they can sometimes condition you to make over calculated decisions, imagining all corner cases and hypotheticals that your software may never encounter. Or at least I am stuck in this loop.